# Avoid browser/client timeouts by returning response header first without streaming or using chunked encoding?

Tags: http, browser, tcp, timeout, connection-timeout

There are similar questions on managing long-running HTTP requests, but the goal is to avoid streaming or chunked encoding.

The reason is to keep a simpler experience for the API user, where they make an API request and receive back an image file in the response -- no need to reassemble chunked/stream data.

Based on posts elsewhere, sending the response headers immediately, before the body is ready, will keep the connection alive.

Chunked encoding lets you do this, but this imposes more work on the user to reassemble the chunked/stream body data.

Is it possible to send *one* response header property back, then send the remaining headers when the body is ready?

Comment: Is it possible - sure. Does it help - maybe or maybe not, maybe for some and not for others. There is no concept of long running responses in the HTTP standard, it is about request and the following response. This does not change with chunked encoding, which is only about not knowing the length up-front but not about delaying the response. Given that the behavior is not standardized the result will depend on the specific implementations.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks. could you kindly post an answer as to how you could return one response header first then return the remaining headers and body later (in whatever language you're most comfortable with)?

Comment: How to do this is totally up to the implementation of the server and there is nothing known about this. Assuming that you have full control of the TCP socket then just send the first headers according to the HTTP standard. If you don't have full control of the socket then it might or might not be possible with whatever you have as server implementation.